# Java ASM, collect all overloading methods and replace the invocation with all the others

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, mutation-testing

Is there a tool/method in ASM to collect all the methods in a class and then replace the invocation of a class with those overloading methods?

I'm trying to use ASM with mutation testing to do these:

- replace a method with its overloading methods
- replace it with another method with the same parameters and return type (different name)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool that does specifically what you want, but it shouldn't be hard to code.

For the second case, it's just a matter of searching for that method, and replacing the name, assuming you don't care about reflection or virtual calls.

For this, you can just implement `MethodVistor.visitMethodInsn()` and replace all the instructions with the desired (owner, name, desc) triple. Note that in the case of inheritance, `owner` might be different than what you expect. For example, suppose you are trying to replace `Foo bar (II)V`, and there is a subclass `Child` of `Foo`. In that case, the client code may invoke the method using the triple `Child bar (II)V` instead.

The first case is more challenging, because the overloaded methods presumably have different type descriptors, and hence you'll have to add bytecode to convert the arguments and/or return type to the right types. However, this is just a matter of reading the ASM documentation and then implementing it.